# UITableView UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator Label

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface

What's the label "Office" called in the following image?

[image]

And how do you set that programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That appears to be the `detailTextView` of a table cell with the `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` style.

You would set the text in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier"];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Ringtone";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Office";
    return cell;
}
```